# How can I export Eclipse compiler settings to a file?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse I have exported code formatting, cleanup, import orders etc to files and checked them into svn.

This is useful for my team so that they can all use the same setup.

However, I can't find a way to do the same for Compiler options. There are quite a few useful settings that aren't switched on by default and its error prone for everyone to change them manually.

I know that I can use FindBugs (and we do through CI) but the Eclipse compiler options are better integrated and faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to share all of those settings is to use Project-specific settings. Open the Project properties and select the various sections that you want to configure (for example, **Java Compiler**, then select the option **Enable project specific settings**.

[image]

Any settings you configure this way are stored in the project in a folder named `.settings`. Check that folder in to source control along with the `.classpath` and `.project` files, and whenever the project is checked out Eclipse will automatically apply the settings. Workspace settings are overridden by project-specific settings, so using this technique it doesn't matter how other workspaces or users have their settings configured.

Comment: Additionally you should do the same with the code formatting and cleanup rules. That way they are automatically applied to all your team members, while with your current solution they need to import those settings manually, one time, right?

Comment: Good points. I will set this up. For some reason I have encountered resistance to this though and people like to setup their own env!

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @E-Riz is perfectly correct. If you find that you need to synchronize more than the listed settings for your team members in the future, then you should also have a look at Googles [workspace mechanic](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/), which allows to automatically apply any set of preferences to a workspace and to check during each start if the local preferences are still valid for the shared setup.